# UICollectionView: ScrollToItem to center cell does not work on horizontal collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a horizontal UICollectionView with a content offset, so that every element (including the left-most item) can be scrolled to the center:

```
let cvOffset = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - tileSize) / 2
collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: cvOffset, bottom: 0, right: cvOffset)
collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: cvOffset, bottom: 0, right: cvOffset)
```

However, when I use `scrollToItem` method, it does only work for the right half of the items. If I choose any item on the left half, the first cell is entered. Do you know why?

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath.init(row: sender.tag, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

Comment: I had done that using `setContentOffset` directly instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is a bug in a `UICollectionView` with flow layout or somehow a desired outcome, but you can do what you need by setting `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`s `sectionInset` to your content inset and then `scrollToItem` will work as expected:

So remove your `contentInset` and just add the following to your layout:

```
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: cvOffset, bottom: 0, right: cvOffset)
```

In my test app it did what it was supposed to, so scrolling to selected cell and centred for all `indexPath`s

Comment: Wow, thank you for this brilliant solution! This works perfectly!

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help, and I learned something new as well, I was sure `contentOffset` way should work and it didn't :)